# Adding functions to a a divi theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, hook

How can I overwrite files in the parent theme with the replacement versions in my child theme? We are using Divi as the parent theme.
We were told, in our functions.php you would create a function with all our modifications, then tell wordpress to hook our function in when et_builder_structure_elements_load runs. Im extremely new to wordpress and php so any help would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add the child theme and activate it. If you haven't read it already, here is a link to the wordpress documentation to do this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#how-to-create-a-child-theme

Note that you cannot remove any function from the parent theme. The parent functions and child functions will run together.

Then you can add an action hook to your functions.php of the child theme like so:

```
<?php

add_action('et_builder_structure_elements_load',function(){
    echo "Doing my function";
})
```

This will run when wordpress calls `do_action('et_builder_structure_elements_load')`